# The constructor ProcessBuilder(String, String, String) is undefined

Tags: java, compiler-errors

In this same IDE eclipse i have two projects both have

```
ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder("cmd.exe", "/c", "command");
```

but in project one it is not showing compile error but in project two it is showing compile error both JRE System Library is jre1.8.0_31

The compile error is the subject-heading of this post ie.

> The constructor ProcessBuilder(String, String, String) is undefined

please help?

Comment: Did you check import line of ProcessBuilder class ? Is the package same ? It could be two different classes from different packages just having same name.  If your IDE does auto import, its easy to make mistake.

Comment: Have you tried reconfiguring your build path? (remove standard lib, re-add standard lib) It fixes problems I have with using fx in Java 8

Comment: @PavelNiedoba.. ProcessBuilder is in `java.lang` package, so there won't be any import statement for that but if it's a user-defined ProcessBuilder class, then there might be some import at the top

Comment: ok first of all thanks for the comments, i tried removing and adding JRE System library twice but it does not fix the error, and @pavel there is no class with name ProcessBuilder & this class is in java.lang package so IDE does not do any imports, but I also tried with using full name with package but no help..i guess IDE gone mad...

Comment: @Arkantos it may be however that some library also defines a `ProcessBuilder` class which has no such constructor; if this particular import is specified then java.lang's will not be used

Comment: Do a Ctrl+Click on your `ProcessBuilder` or select ProcessBuilder text and do F3, which will take you to the source, then you can see if it's in lang or some other package

Comment: Your JRE System Library is pointing to JDK right not JRE

Comment: first when i tried it tells me to attach source, so i attach source from my JDK 1.8_25, and then it took me to same java.lang.ProcessBuilder where there was contrcutor like ProcessBuilder(String.. command)

Comment: @Arkantos it is pointing to jre 1.8.0_31

Comment: @user2493303 is it pointing at java.lang.ProcessBuilder?

Comment: ya after i attach source from jdk 1.8 dir it took me to ProcessBuilder class in lang package

Comment: Usually JRE System Library in eclipse build path should point to JDK. If you have jdk 1.8.0_31 point to that path if not point it to your JDK 1.8_25

Comment: i change the compiler settings from 1.4 to 1.7 in eclipse and problem fixed now ..thanks anyways

Comment: Wow.. didn't even think of that.. good to know :)

Comment: Too bad, I did, just would not expect anyone could be still on 1.4. Jdk 1.4 does not have (String ... paramList) notation

Answer (score 3):

For me in eclipse I right clicked on my project; went to properties; chose java compiler; My compliance level was stuck at 1.4; so I bumped it up to the latest - 1.8 & it worked after that.

Answer (score 0):

I had this exact same error.  I'm running eclipse in Ubuntu.  My line of code with the error was

```
ProcessBuilder builder2 = new ProcessBuilder("cmd.exe", "/c", "rasphone -h irid");
```

My solution was similar to Reece's.  Except my compliance level was at 1.7 (and there was no 1.8)

But I went to 1.5, and for some reason that worked.  Weird.

Answer (score -1):

Try this.

```
 String[] commands ={"cmd.exe", "/c", "command"};
 ProcessBuilder processBuilder = new ProcessBuilder(commands);
```